# triggering a function on hover event for button in pygtk

Tags: python, events, button, pygtk

I want to change the text of the button when mouse hovers on it,

Like this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7vCf_lvUsY

How to add an event when mouse hovers on a button in pygtk

I cudnt find this in the documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to connect to the `enter-notify-event` and `leave-notify-event` signals of the button. Don't forget to enable them in the event mask. I don't think you need an `EventBox`.

Comment: thnx I'll try it and will get back to u

Answer (score 1):

You can add a gtk.EventBox() of the size of the button and add button in it. And you can easily add an event for hovering.